# What if we clean several shopping questions..?

Tags: support, scope, vote-to-close

Today, I accidentally went through the questions under [telescopes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telescopes) tag and all questions confused me *totally*. Looks like, there are many questions that seem to me like *off-topic*. I've listed several questions (There are more). They're confusing me a lot... (on-topic or off-topic).

**Could someone suggest me how they are ON (or OFF) and why..?**

1) [Telescopes to avoid as a beginner?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25052)
2) [Is building your own reflector telescope worth it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26037)
3) [How to determine what size telescope to buy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25123) (I'm wondering how this is on-topic even after my VTC)
4) [How do you clean a dusty lens?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24892) (This is *too ridiculous*)
5) [Where can I find information for how to create amateur radio telescope?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25502)
6) [Novice interested in buying a used telescope. What questions should I ask?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26535)

All are not *necessarily* off-topic or not constructive. Maybe someone could explain about the on-topic...

Comment: Well, I've VTC'd some posts to be closed. But, I didn't flag because I'm not sure. And, I don't want the mods to go here & there following *flag rain*. VTC is not a big problem. It would be disabled after some grace period :-)

Comment: These would have been on topic at Astronomy, which I don't think was as particular about removing shopping recommendations or list questions as we are. So it's quite possible that all of them are off topic here. But I will leave it to the community to discuss - it would be best if any which are off topic can be closed by the full 5 people.

Comment: #3 could use a better title, but it's not a shopping recommendation. Look at the question body.

Comment: The dusty lens one seems OK to me. It's a problem pertaining to astronomers, so it is on topic.

Comment: @Manishearth: Huh? - Cleaning a telescope lens (optic) is equivalent to a lens in camera too. I have a thought that it is very basic. From several answers I see there, It makes me think that *it is very basic*..? Even, the "basic" is not a problem. "Cleaning?" - I don't think its *physical* :-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: Um, we have nothing against basic questions. And, similar to software questions, if your question is about a _tool used by physicists/astronomers_, it ought no be fine, imo.